# Git rebase - remote deletes a file and local rebase applies changes to another file

Tags: git, rebase, git-rebase

Simple scenario:

Remote:

```
git init
touch a.py && git add a.py && git commit -am "Add a.py"
touch b.py && git add b.py && git commit -am "Add b.py"
```

Local:

```
git clone REMOTE_URL
echo "Bob Loblaw" >> a.py && git commit -am "Append to a.py"
```

Remote:

```
git rm a.py && git commit -am "Remove a.py"
```

Local:

```
git fetch origin
git rebase origin/master
```

Output:

```
$ cat b.py
Bob Loblaw
```

Why are my local changes to a.py applied to b.py instead of getting a rebase conflict, e.g.

```
CONFLICT (delete/modify): a.py deleted in HEAD and modified in Append to a.py. Version Append to a.py of a.py left in tree.
```

If it makes a difference, I'm using git version 1.7.4.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I heard of this weird issue before.

The problems arises from the fact that `a.py` and `b.py` are identical in their content.

Git uses heuristics based on the contents in order to detect a file renaming, and in your case the heuristic confused the deletion of `a.py` with a renaming of the same to `b.py`, since they were both empty and the change applied is very small.

This happened because the default `recursive` merge strategy, according to the [documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-merge.html),

> can detect and handle merges involving renames

Apparently this was fixed/improved in modern versions of git, since on my machine I cannot reproduce the problem with Git v1.8.1.3.

You can update your Git (strongly suggested) or try with a different merge strategy, which doesn't handle renames, like `resolve` (though it has some drawbacks, read the doc for more info).

**EDIT**

A further alternative would be to play with the `--rename-threshold` option of the `recursive` merge strategy, setting it to `M100%`, which according to the doc of [`git-diff`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-diff.html) will

> limit detection to exact renames

The git command would be

```
git rebase -Xrename-threshold=M100% origin/master
```

Answer (score 0):

When following your steps, I do get a merge conflict during the rebase (as it should be):

```
gittest/loc$ git rebase origin/master
[...]
CONFLICT (modify/delete): a.py deleted in HEAD and modified in Append to a.py.
Version Append to a.py of a.py left in tree.
Failed to merge in the changes.
```

You probably did something subtly different - or maybe there is a problem with your git installation or a bug in your git (though that seems unlikely).

I used git 1.8.1.1 on Debian Linux.